# Internet Explorer Developer Center error : HTML1405 : Invalid character: U+0000 NULL. Null characters should not be used

Tags: html, windows, internet-explorer

I'm testing a website with Internet Explorer 10 on windows 8.

I have this error and i don't understand what does it mean :

> HTML1405 "Invalid character: U+0000 NULL. Null characters should not
>   be used."

Here is the documentation on Internet Explorer Developer Center / F12 developer tools console error messages but there is no suggestions for how to fix the errors :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh180764%28v=vs.85%29

This error is at the end of the source code of the website, after </html> but there is nothing here.

Comment: Other browsers don't complain?

Comment: no error on chrome, firefox, safari, only IE.

Comment: Try running your site through this validator and see if it helps pin it down: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Check if the source code contains the character with the code point zero (NIL, U+0000, \0...) at the end. Not sure what to say more.

Comment: looks like some none-visible control characters in your code?

Comment: I've validated the source code (html5) on W3C and there is no error. How can i check if there is a non visible characters ? I'm using netbeans but i can use other tools.

Comment: Try any decent hex editor; F3 in freeCommander or totalCommander

Comment: Is it the right link to download freeCommander http://www.freecommander.com/ ?

Comment: Have you validated the document by URL at the W3C Markup Validator? Can you share the URL? (If you validate via copy and paste, the offending NUL character(s) may get lost.)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I'm using validation by url. Here is the link. Sorry, the website is still in development so some functionalities still doesn't work but you can see the error in IE developer tools console : http://www.echo-in.com/home.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML document as sent to a browser contains, in addition to some newline characters, a NUL character U+0000 after the end tag `</html>`. I checked this the clumsy way of using Rex Swain’s [HTTP Viewer](http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html) to analyze [your page](http://www.echo-in.com/home.php), with the Display Format option set to Hex. At the end of the result listing, there is the following line:

```
47FF0: 3C2F68746D6C3E0D 0A300D0A0D0A     </html>• •0••••
```

So it seems that IE 10 is right here and the W3C validator is wrong. I’m not sure exactly how the W3C HTML5 CR defines the characters allowed in HTML source (it seems to say this rather indirectly, via the parsing algorithms), but by XML specs as well as previous HTML specs, NUL is simply disallowed.

In any case, NUL does not do any good there and should be removed, but on the other hand, it is difficult to see how it could do any actual harm either especially when appearing after the end tag of the document.

Comment: Thanx for this clear analyze. Do you know how could i remove this character ?

Comment: +1 This was the fix for me, removing the extra new-line after the closing `</html>` tag resolved this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try converting your file as UTF-8 without BOM, I had the same problem, worked for me!

My texteditor Notepad++ has an option at "Encoding > Encode in UTF-8 without BOM".

See [What's different between UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom) for more info.